# Unable to access resources after moving to folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resources, visual-studio-2017

I added a bunch of `.resx` files to my project in the root directory, and have always been able to access them without any problem in my views with, for example:

```
Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("ResourceName")
```

Now that there  are quit a few files,I decided to tidy up by adding them all to a `Resources` folder. I also created some new `.resx` files directly in the new folder.

However, I am now unable to access these with:

> 'Resources' is inaccessible due to its protection level

I tried changing the the Access Modifer to Internal, Public and No Code Generation, but none of these work.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that moving the resx files to a new folder added them to their own namespace, so I just had to add this to the top of the view:

```
@using WebsiteName.Resources
```